# Proving the inverse of a two variable function

Tags: functions

Prove that $f_3(x,y) = (y,-x)$ is the inverse of $f_1(x,y) = (-y,x)$

So far I have tried to prove this with the Proof of Inverse Function Theorem:

$f_1 \circ f_3(x,y) = (x,y)$

and

$f_3 \circ f_1(x,y) = (x,y)$

Both of which are true, so does this mean that $f_3$ is the inverse of $f_1$? Have I done this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$